# Rest parameter validation with annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a rest controller that takes in a `Dto`. One of `Dto`'s attribute is and `id` of entity to update, however this entity might be locked for update (flag on entity). I have created a custom `ConstraintValidator` for `id` attribute to check if entity id locked and it returns code 400 (which is as expected but not desired since the request was valid). Is this correct approach to validate input data with annotations to check for business conditions?

Or should I define a validation service which, in case of business conditions are not met, will throw whatever I want?

Or is there another approach which i did not consider yet?

Will provide code if necessary.

Comment: No, it's not correct to do this. Validation is intended for data integrity, not application state checks. In fact, if the object is locked, you should probably put it in a queue to perform the operation later.

Comment: ok, this seems reasonable to use Validation for data integrity, but then to check application state i should do this with dedicated service? is it correct approach to catch method call paramthers on method call and validate them on that level?